# "Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ng due" to while running karma test runner

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, karma-runner, chai

I am trying to run test cases for my application but stuck in between. Its giving the below error -

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ng due to:
>   TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'Function.prototype.bind.apply')
>   .......
>   ......
>   {path}/test/unit/generate-form-directive.js:24

*Test file is (generate-form-directive.js)* -

```
describe("UNIT DIRECTIVE: generateForm", function () {
    "use strict";

    // Angular injectables
    var $compile, $rootScope, $httpBackend;

    // Module defined (non-Angular) injectables
    var $scope, directiveScope, pagerVm;

    // Local variables used for testing
    var template;

    // Initialize modules
    beforeEach(function () {
        module("TestDataModule");
    });

    beforeEach(function () {
        inject(function (_$compile_, _$rootScope_, _$httpBackend_) {
            $compile = _$compile_;
            $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
            $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        });   //Line no 24
    });

    it("test message", function() {
        console.log("Hello");
    });
});
```

*My Karma file (karma.conf.js)* -

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: "",
        frameworks: ["mocha", "chai", "sinon"],
        files: [

            "node_modules/angular/angular.js",
            "node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js",

            // Add template files
            "src/**/*.html",

            "src/commons/js/*.js",
            "src/commons/services/*.js",
            "src/commons/directives/**/*.js",
            "src/modules/**/*.js",

            // Add all the test files
            "test/unit/*.js",
        ],

        exclude: [],

        preprocessors: {
            "src/**/*.js": "coverage"
        },

        reporters: ["mocha", "coverage"],
        mochaReporter: {
            // full, autowatch, minimal
            output: "autowatch",
            ignoreSkipped: false
        },

        browserNoActivityTimeout: 20000,
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true,
        browsers: ["PhantomJS"],
        singleRun: true,
        coverageReporter: {
            dir: "./coverage",
            reporters: [{
                type: "cobertura",
                subdir: ".",
                file: "cobertura.xml"
            }, {
                type: "text"
            }]
        }
    });
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The minimatch pattern ('/**/*') did not worked in `karma.conf.js`.

You have two options:

1) Try to change your minimatch version and see if it helps.

2) Or specify each file instead of using the minimatch pattern ("/**/*.js").

Change karma configuration file for something like this:

```
        // Add template files
        "src/views/view1.html",
        "src/views/view2.html",

        "src/commons/js/myJs1.js",
        "src/commons/services/service1.js",
        "src/commons/services/service2.js",
        "src/commons/directives/directive1.js",
        "src/modules/moduleName/moduleNAme1.js",

        // Add all the test files
        "test/unit/testFile1.js",
```